# Suggest DataSet for Sentiment Analysis on Dutch languages

Tags: sentiment-analysis

Can anybody provide any links for any training dataset for sentiment analysis on Dutch languages? I googled trying to find maybe movie review on Dutch but didn't find website with persons review like in IMDB

Comment: This question might be a better fit for [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @StephenRauch and E_net4   . Oh, thanks, didn't know that exist such branch. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this free Dutch [corpora](http://corporafromtheweb.org/nlcow14/)

Comment: Please do not add link-only posts. :)